# Inserting to Sqlite is slow

Tags: java, sqlite, sql-insert, mysql-slow-query-log

I am new to Database.

I am tying to insert 22000 word to a sqlite DB but it is taking forever to complete

```
for (int i=0;i<s.size();i++){               
    String sql = "INSERT INTO WORD (word) VALUES ("+"'"+s.get(i)+"'"+");";
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
}
```

Table name is WORD and field name is word(which is a `String`)
Here s is an arrylist and s.get(i) returns a string... I have made the connection and trying to update
the table.

It is very slow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does something change if you try with a batch insert?

Comment: How many times to you insert 22 000 entries? What is "slow", as in, how long does it actually take?

Comment: It's in another programming language, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite

Comment: i don't know why but u can use enhanced loop.not so different

Answer (score 1):

Its slow because you are firing 22000 queries to the database. You should insert in batches. That will fix the problem. Even if a single insert takes 10ms total time is like 3.5 minutes!!

A simple insert query with batches of 2 will look like this

```
"INSERT INTO WORD (word) VALUES ("+"'"+s.get(i)+"'"+"), ("+"'"+s.get(i+1)+"'"+");";
```

This will reduce the time by half. Now you will have to programatically insert more of these values.

Comment: "Might want to"? Are you guessing? Wouldn't it be better to also explain to the OP what a batch insert is, and how he would accomplish it? The very first sentence is "I am new to this", so there's a large possibility he doesn't know what a batch insert is.

Comment: There is an option to edit the answer just in case my answer is insufficient. Thanks for pointing out the issues anyways il update it.